# ANDROID: How to properly link against static libraries while creating shared libraries with dependencies on the static ones

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, shared-libraries, protocol-buffers

I have to use some c++ code in my android application. This code was used successfully in an iOS project.
The code depends on 2 external libraries: zero-mq and protocol buffers.

I compiled the zmq library as an static library like explained [here](http://zeromq.org/build:android). I added the static (.a) library and the .jar to my project.

I created the protobuf library with the following configurations:

```
./configure --host=arm-eabi --with-sysroot=x/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm CC="x/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot x/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm" --enable-cross-compile --with-protoc=protoc LIBS=-lc
make
```

I changed the real directories to x to make them shorter.

In my Android Project(IDE: Android Studio) I prepared everything which is necessary. I created a JNI Folder and deactivated the auto-creation of the makefiles.

Application.mk:

```
APP_MODULE := proxy
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions --std=c++11
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a             ##all later
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := zmq_static
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := zmq/libzmq.a
include $(PREBUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_MODULE := protobuf_static1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := protobuf/libprotobuf.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := google/protobuf protobuf/
include $(PREBUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_MODULE := protobuf_static2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := protobuf/libprotobuf-lite.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := google/protobuf protobuf/
include $(PREBUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_MODULE := protobuf_static3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := protobuf/libprotoc.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := google/protobuf protobuf/
include $(PREBUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := proxy
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -I/include -pthread -lpthread -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -        frtti
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -I/include -pthread -lpthread -D__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ -frtti
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
usersession.cpp\



## LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true    will compile the code but   shutdown on runtime

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +=     C:\Users\M\Dropbox\Workspace\ndk_swig_test\app\src\main\jni
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += C:\Users\M\Dropbox\Workspace\ndk_swig_test\app\src\arm\jni
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += C:\Users\M\Dropbox\Workspace\ndk_swig_test\app\src\debug\jni
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +=  C:\Users\M\Dropbox\Workspace\ndk_swig_test\app\src\armDebug\jni
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \zmq
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \protobuf

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := zmq_static protobuf_static1 protobuf_static2 protobuf_static3
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := zmq_static protobuf_static1 protobuf_static2 protobuf_static3

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The zmq library is in the subdirectory zmq and the protobuf library is in the subfolder protobuf.

Now the linking of the Objects still does not work. The Error Output when I execute ndk-build:

```
C:\Users\M\Dropbox\Workspace\ndk_swig_test\app\src\main\jni>ndk-build
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libproxy.so
C:/Users/M/Documents/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-   libstdc++/4.9/include/ext/new_allocator.h:127: error: undefined reference to    'ControlledInstance::ControlledInstan  (std::shared_ptr<protogen::Application>, std:
:shared_ptr<protogen::Role>, std::shared_ptr<protogen::User>)'
C:/Users/M/Documents/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-   libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:511: error: undefined reference to   'protogen::User::User()'
C:/Users/M/Documents/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-  libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:914: error: undefined reference to    'google::protobuf::internal::empty  tring_'
   C:/Users/M/Dropbox/Workspace/ndk_swig_test/app/src/main//jni/controlledinstance.h    :23: error: undefined reference to 'protogen::MetaGraph::~MetaGraph()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: ***    [C:/Users/M/Dropbox/Workspace/ndk_swig_test/app/src/main//obj/local/armeabi-  v7a/libproxy.so] Error 1
```

I tried many versions of the Android.mk and recreated the library more than once with different options which I found all over the internet.
I also looked at dozens of threads on stackoverflow which did not help me.(I'm not allowed to link them because of low reputation)
Additionally i read most of the doc files from the ndk e.g. [PREBUILTS](https://gitorious.org/mingw-android-ndk/mingw-android-ndk/source/751583709c4b87ad67f759dabf25ea6a2d8fd692:docs/PREBUILTS.html#LNaN-NaN).
I added some other directories to my JNI directory e.g. the directory with the original files and directories (compiler, io, stubs...). I think this directory should offer the export of the necessary methods if the prebuild library was successfully linked to my shared library - which is not the case. 
I tried far more than I can explain in few minutes and I think it would be overkill if i added everything I've tried because nothing helped.

Because this is my first question I dont have the reputation to include more than 2 links. Sorry for that.

Comment: Have you tried the extern "C" { } on the exposed functions in the code? That is one of the common pitfalls working with shared libraries.

Comment: I'm not trying to call functions yet. The extern C pattern is used in the wrapper for the methods i want to call. Yet im getting the errors while compiling the shared library

Comment: To create shared libraries you need to specify -fPIC at compile time as an additional flag.

Comment: The NDK uses this flag by default to produce position indepencent code and executable (PIC & PIE). I still tried to add the flag to the makefile of the shared library so it will be executed at compiletime but it still throws the same errors. I think the problem is the linking of the static library. However, thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may probably be other issues as well, but you at least have got a typo - it should be `include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)`, as in, `BUILT`, not `BUILD`.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much - this actually helps. The compiler now recognizes the static libraries. Sadly my used toolchain for the protobuf library seems to be wrong so i get a lot of incopatible target errors. But I'm really happy for this progress. I accepted you answer.